# As soon ... as find

Tags: meaning

> And since these beggars are unchristened and unregistered, **the local constabulary will as soon drop them in a communal grave as find a name for a gravestone**. (*Peaky Blinders* S05E03)

Is *as soon ... as find* the same as *as soon as possible*? Why is *drop them in a communal grave* put between *soon** and the second *as*?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not the same sense as *as soon as possible,* it's *would (just) as soon.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would-just-as-soon

They are as ready to take action A as they are to take action B.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idiomatic usage of *as soon...as...*. It has the same meaning as *rather...than...* or *sooner...than...* (CaGEL p1133). The approximate meaning of the sentence is:

> the local constabulary prefers dropping them in a communal grave to
>   finding a name for a gravestone

Comment: Correct +1.  But another example would be helpful - e.g. The miserable neighbours would ***as soon look the other way as smile when they meet you***.